# How do I use the same object for multiple hooks in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I have the following hook config (in hooks.php)

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'     => 'MY_DataCollection',
    'function'  => 'init',
    'filename'  => 'MY_DataCollection.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);

$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'class'     => 'MY_DataCollection',
    'function'  => 'post_controller',
    'filename'  => 'MY_DataCollection.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);
```

What I want to do is have the class instantiated in the `post_controller_constructor` and then have the `init` method run. Then for `post_controller` run the `post_controller` but using the very same instance. CodeIgniter is instantiating the class again however.

Next I tried something slightly clever I thought:

```
require_once APPPATH . 'hooks/MY_DataCollection.php';
$collection = new MY_DataCollection;

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function'  => array($collection, 'init'),
    'filename'  => 'MY_DataCollection.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);

$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'function'  => array($collection, 'post_controller'),
    'filename'  => 'MY_DataCollection.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);
```

That doesn't work, as the hook class in CI does a require and I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class MY_DataCollection in /var/www/application/hooks/MY_DataCollection.php on line 7
```

So I got rid of the file path info:

```
require_once APPPATH . 'hooks/MY_DataCollection.php';
$collection = new MY_DataCollection;

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'function'  => array($collection, 'init')
);

$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'function'  => array($collection, 'post_controller')
);
```

Doesn't even attempt to run, as in the `CI_Hooks` class there is this check in `_run_hook`:

```
if ( ! isset($data['filepath']) OR ! isset($data['filename']))
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

I think I'm going to have to override this function by extending this class, but I just can't believe that this situation hasn't been encountered by someone else before and that there's not any easier way of solving it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmz, it seems you need to store the instance of the needed class somewhere.
Maybe you could do something like this:

```
class MyHooks 
{
    public static $object_you_need;

    public function init() 
    {
        $object = new MyObject();
        $object->init();
        self::$object_you_need = $object;
    }

    public function post_controller()
    {
        $object = self::$object_you_need;
        // do stuff with that object
    }
}
```

Doesn't feel pretty, but I think it works.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, involves the least amount of code for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is already solved on the **CI3** here is how to fix it on **CI2**

- Just create a `MY_Hooks.php` on your `app/core directory`
- Copy the `Hooks.php` class on the CI 3 Repository and put it in your
  `MY_Hooks.php` but the class    name will be `MY_Hooks Extends
  CI_Hooks` it is located on `system/core/hooks.php`
- change the `call_hook` function to `_call_hook` (just add a underscore '_')
- change the `private _run_hook` to `public`
- next step, is lay back and drink beer

Here is to test if it is working

```
class Hook_hook{
    private $init = 'function inits not called';

    public function inits(){
        $this->init = 'function inits called';
    }

    public function load(){
        echo '<script>alert("'.$this->init.'")</script>';
    }
}
```

Sample config on **config/hooks.php**

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'     => 'Hook_hook',
    'function'  => 'inits',
    'filename'  => 'Hook_hook.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);

$hook['post_controller'][] = array(
    'class'     => 'Hook_hook',
    'function'  => 'load',
    'filename'  => 'Hook_hook.php',
    'filepath'  => 'hooks'
);
```